# asp.net mvc 3 validation summary not showing via unobtrusive validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

I'm having problems getting the asp.net MVC client-side validation to work how I want it.

I have it basically working, however, the validation summary is not displayed until the user clicks the submit button, even though the individual inputs are being highlighted as invalid as the user tabs/clicks etc their way through the form.    This is all happening client-side.

I would have thought the that the validation summary would be displayed as soon as an input field was discovered that was invalid.

Is this behaviour by design?  Is there any way around it, as I would like the validation summary to be displayed as soon as it is discovered that one of the input fields is invalid.

My code is basically,

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model);   
        ...
```

And my `_Layout.cshtml` references `jquery-1.4.4.min.js`.

Comment: According to the authors of Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework by Apress, this is by design.  In their chapter on model validation, they have an example of client-side validation and they point out that while the per-field messages are updated when the input is altered, the validation summary only changes when the form submit button is pressed.  (They mention this on pages 630-632.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can setup the validation summary to be triggered a lot more often, in onready:

```
var validator = $('form').data('validator');
validator.settings.showErrors = function (map, errors) {
    this.defaultShowErrors();
    this.checkForm();
    if (this.errorList.length)
        $(this.currentForm).triggerHandler("invalid-form", [this]);
    else
        $(this.currentForm).resetSummary();
    }
}
```

Here's the resetSummary used above:

```
jQuery.fn.resetSummary = function () {
    var form = this.is('form') ? this : this.closest('form');
    form.find("[data-valmsg-summary=true]")
        .removeClass("validation-summary-errors")
        .addClass("validation-summary-valid")
        .find("ul")
        .empty();
    return this;
};
```

Comment: Great solution, works for me. Only change i had was to hang it off of validator.

Answer (score 5):

I used a version of Torbjörn Nomells answer

Except here I hang resetSummary off the validator object

```
$.validator.prototype.resetSummary= function () {
    var form = $(this.currentForm);
    form.find("[data-valmsg-summary=true]")
        .removeClass("validation-summary-errors")
        .addClass("validation-summary-valid")
        .find("ul")
        .empty();
    return this;
};
```

Then change calling it to

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
        this.defaultShowErrors();
        this.checkForm();
        if (this.errorList.length) {
            $(this.currentForm).triggerHandler("invalid-form", [this]);
        } else {
            this.resetSummary();
        }
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar question open here: [How to display MVC 3 client side validation results in validation summary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150476/how-to-display-mvc-3-client-side-validation-results-in-validation-summary) but the suggested solution by Darin does not seem to work the way I (and probably you) want it to.

Comment: Yes, it looks like we have essentially the same problem

Comment: I have been doing a bit of digging into the jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js code. and from what I can tell, the function which sets the validation summary is function onErrors, which is not called until the user tries to submit.